# Google Drive API: How do I list all files in a shared folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I have a google service account and I have it successfully uploading files to a shared folder (i.e. I created a folder with a normal google account, shared it with the service account, and uploaded files to that shared folder).

When I open this shared folder with my normal google account, I can see the files that were created by the google service account. However, when I create another file in the shared folder from my normal google account, it does *not* show up when I pull the file list.

I'm doing:

```js
  //  does not work
  const results = await drive.files.list({
    corpora: 'allDrives', // just in case, don't know if this makes a difference
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
    supportsAllDrives: true,
  });

  console.log(results.data.files);
```

with the node SDK 48 (i.e. `"googleapis": "^48.0.0"`)

---

**How do I get this service account to pull *all* the shared files in this folder regardless if the service account created that file or not?**

Answer (score 2):

OMG I figured it out after banging my head against the wall for a while.

I had this:

```js
  const client = await google.auth.getClient({
    credentials: {/* ... */},
    //                                      WRONG 
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
  });
```

Just replace the scope with this:

```js
  const client = await google.auth.getClient({
    credentials: {/* ... */},
    //                              ✅ Correct 
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  });
```

---

I'm not sure if widening the scope is exactly what you want but it seems this issue related to scopes so if you're having this issue, [start there](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth).